# Replace Demo content with fully functional one

Tags: ios, iphone

So I have iPhone 5c ME561LP/A with demo content. Can I replace the demo content with fully functional iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, all you should have to do is wipe and restore it to the latest iOS version via iTunes:

> ### [Use iTunes on your Mac or PC to restore your iPhone, iPad, or iPod to factory settings](https://support.apple.com/en-ie/HT201252)
>
> A factory restore erases the information and settings on your iPhone, iPad, or iPod and installs the latest iOS or iPod software.

Comment: That worked like a charm :)